# Unable to call event to add widget

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

*I am using Gridstack to add widgets to the page and I am using following code. So, when I am trying to click on the options (chart, image, table) button, I am getting error*

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/gridstack/dist/gridstack.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="grid-stack">
    <!-- Your widgets will be added here -->
  </div>

  <button id="add-widget-btn">Add Widget</button>

  <!-- Pop-up container -->
  <div id="popup-container" style="display: none;">
    <h3>Select a Widget:</h3>
    <button class="widget-selector" data-widget-type="chart">Chart</button>
    <button class="widget-selector" data-widget-type="table">Table</button>
    <button class="widget-selector" data-widget-type="image">Image</button>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/gridstack/dist/gridstack-all.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function () {
      var grid = GridStack.init();

      $('#add-widget-btn').click(function () {
        $('#popup-container').show();
      });

      $('.widget-selector').click(function () {
        var widgetType = $(this).data('widget-type');
        var widgetContent = getWidgetContent(widgetType);
        addWidget(widgetContent);
        $('#popup-container').hide();
      });

      function getWidgetContent(widgetType) {
       
        if (widgetType === 'chart') {
          return '<div class="grid-stack-item" data-gs-width="4" data-gs-height="4">Chart Widget Content</div>';
        } else if (widgetType === 'table') {
          return '<div class="grid-stack-item" data-gs-width="6" data-gs-height="4">Table Widget Content</div>';
        } else if (widgetType === 'image') {
          return '<div class="grid-stack-item" data-gs-width="2" data-gs-height="4">Image Widget Content</div>';
        }
      }

      function addWidget(content) {
        var gridStackItem = $('<div>').html(content);
        grid.addWidget(gridStackItem);
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Error:

> gridstack.ts:1475 Uncaught TypeError: e.getAttribute is not a function
> at R._readAttr (gridstack.ts:1475:29)
> at R.addWidget (gridstack.ts:444:24)
> at addWidget (Home.html:52:14)
> at HTMLButtonElement. (Home.html:35:9)
> at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:43064)
> at v.handle (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:41048)

I have installed Gridstack using "npm install gridstack" in VS Code and created home.html page (whose code is shared above)